# Is it possible to force smooth implicit scrolling for Flutter's accessibility focus system?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm currently adapting a Flutter app to work with Android TV devices. Documentation on this is sparse, but I've managed to feel my way through the process by using the accessibility focus system for directional navigation using the standard remote.

However, in one of my layouts I'm using a `PageView` containing some grids of items, the grid separated out into pages for better directional navigation ergonomics. As expected, creating a `PageView` with `allowImplicitScrolling: true` allows you to navigate between pages by moving the focus reticle off the side of the grid. However, implicit scrolling in any context never has any animation accompanying it, just transitioning to the next view position instantly. This ends up not looking very good. In reality, this same problem applies to *all* implicit scrolling, whether in a `PageView`, `ListView`, `GridView`, or any scrolling view at all.

```dart
Widget _buildPaginatedGrid(BuildContext build) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(build).size.height - gameHeroHeight(context),
        child: PageView(
          allowImplicitScrolling: true,
          controller: _pageController,
          children: [
            _buildRawGrid(build), //just display the same grid twice for testing
            _buildRawGrid(build)
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I know this sort of scrolling is driven by calls to `RenderObject.showOnScreen`, obviously with a duration of zero, so I attempted to create a `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget` with a subclass of `RenderProxyBox` that overrides the `RenderObject.showOnScreen` method to force a duration. Yet, no matter where I put this thing, around each individual grid item, around the grid, around the `PageView`, no animation ever shows during implicit scrolling, and in fact, my override method is never even called. It's like the call never propagates to it no matter where in the widget hierarchy it's placed.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class RenderFocusSmoothScroll extends RenderProxyBox {
  RenderFocusSmoothScroll({RenderBox child}) : super(child);
  @override
  void showOnScreen({
    RenderObject descendant,
    Rect rect,
    Duration duration = Duration.zero,
    Curve curve = Curves.ease,
  }) {
    print("showOnScreen");
    super.showOnScreen(descendant: descendant, rect: rect, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.ease);
  }
}

class FocusSmoothScroll extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const FocusSmoothScroll({
    Key key,
    Widget child,
  })  : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderFocusSmoothScroll createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderFocusSmoothScroll();
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, RenderFocusSmoothScroll renderObject) {

  }
}
```

Documentation on implicit scrolling using the focus system is a bit lacking, as is documentation on properly overriding `RenderObject` methods to enforce custom handling of these propagating calls, so any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `RenderObject.showOnScreen` should be called **by you**, not by a framework, so good news: no need for a custom `RenderProxyBox` and `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget`

Comment: AndroidTV isn't a supported build target for Flutter, so while it's technically possible, you are going to be mostly on your own. You are firmly in uncharted territory, so I wish you the best of luck in finding help on any issues you may come across.

Comment: @pskink in this particular situation, during implicit scrolling, the method must be getting called internally since the focused widget IS being shown on screen in response to a user gesture, but I'm not making any call to it. It's just obviously being called with a zero duration. [see here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics/allowImplicitScrolling.html)

Comment: *"and in fact, my override method is never even called."* and *"It's just obviously being called with a zero duration"* - so my question is: is it called or not?

Comment: @pskink well I assume that method must be getting called on SOME `RenderObject`s since that's what the documentation says, and it looks like that's how it operates visually, but when I try to override the method, my version just doesn't get called during the implicit scroll. That's the disconnect, I'm wondering exactly how this could be. It makes sense, the implicit scrolling system would use `showOnScreen` to scroll the container and show the element that next gains focus on screen, just with no animation.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I figured it out. Turns out the call to `showOnScreen` is actually in the framework's own `FocusTraversalPolicy` source code (`lib/src/widgets/focus_traversal.dart`). I never expected that, I thought the focus traversal policy was exclusively for establishing directionality relationships between widgets, not actually scrolling them onto the screen. I just needed to override the body of a particular function:

```dart
@protected
void _focusAndEnsureVisible(FocusNode node, {ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy alignmentPolicy = ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.explicit}) {
  node.requestFocus();
  Scrollable.ensureVisible(node.context, alignment: 1.0, alignmentPolicy: alignmentPolicy);
}
```

That call to `ensureVisible` includes no duration, hence, the target will instantly be scrolled to. I ended up needing to basically duplicate most of this module into my own project, since there's not any way to redirect the built-in `ReadingOrderTraversalPolicy` to use a different implementation of that module-private function. Not ideal of course, that function is obviously not intended to ever be overridden, but you absolutely can.

```dart
/// Overridden for smooth scrolling.
@protected
void _focusAndEnsureVisible(FocusNode node, {ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy alignmentPolicy = ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.explicit}) {
  node.requestFocus();
  Scrollable.ensureVisible(
    node.context, 
    alignment: 1.0, 
    alignmentPolicy: alignmentPolicy, 
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), 
    curve: Curves.ease,
  );
}
```

So, duplicating the subclasses and mixins from that file and renaming `ReadingOrderTraversalPolicy` to `SmoothReadingOrderTraversalPolicy`, I ended up just sticking a `DefaultFocusTraversal` widget in the builder wrapper of my top level `MaterialApp`, as such:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '...',
      theme: /* ... */,
      home: SplashView(),
      navigatorKey: Globals.rootNavigatorKey,
      initialRoute: '/splash',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        // ...
      },
      onGenerateRoute: _generateRoute,
      builder: (context, widget) => DefaultFocusTraversal(
        policy: SmoothReadingOrderTraversalPolicy(), //imported from my own copy
        child: Stack(children: [widget, /* ... */]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And now implicit scrolling is smooth! If anybody else runs into this problem, I hope this will be helpful.

Thanks to @pskink for prompting me to look a bit deeper into where the method call was coming from, I was just stumped before I thought to look inside the traversal policy itself.

Comment: Cool, thanks for that hint! I'm currently working on an Android TV app, and that really came in handy. One issue is thouh, I added the Duration() directly in the `focus_traversal.dart`file, for testing purposes. Would you mind sharing, how exactly you implemented `SmoothReadingOrderTraversalPolicy`? Thanks!

Comment: @FrobtheBuilder do you mind adding a little bit more what you meant by `duplicating the subclasses and mixins` did you really all the mixins like scrollable.dart, framework.dart, focus_manager.dart etc.. to your project? I'm just trying to understand how and where you did the override.